# Showing a DialogFragment in PreferenceFragment with AndroidX Namespace

Tags: android, androidx

We are currently migrating our Android app the new androidx namespace as described on the official developer pages here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Unfortunately some of our old implementation seems to be broken. We are reusing a DialogFragment (which is originally used outside of the app settings) in one of our `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragment`s. After the migration to androidx the DialogFragment now needs a `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager` instance to be shown - which can no longer be received by calling

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

in the PreferenceFragment. This call will still provide an instance of `android.app.FragmentManager`. I guess this is because PreferenceFragment is not derived from `androidx.fragment`.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and happens to know a solution how I can still reuse the dialog in the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct FragmentManager we need to inherit from `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat` instead of `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragment`. This solved our problem.

See [Google Developer Homepage](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) for more info about PreferenceFragmentCompat